kubectl apply does not remove environment variables
I am trying to use kubectl apply -f dep.yml in order to remove an environment variable from an existing deployment
when I run the command, I get a confirmation message
deployment.apps/XXXX configured

but then when I inspect the deployment again, the environment variable is still there
I verified I am working against the correct deployment name in the correct namespace.
Also, if I change other parameters, for example, change a label value - the change is applied. Only deleting fields seems to be problematic.
any idea what might be causing this?
thanks in advance!

This question is similar to: Can kubectl delete environment variable?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Here are the options you may consider :

Use set env command wherein it removes an existing variable from deployment.

kubectl set env deployment/DEPLOYMENT_NAME VARIABLE_NAME-


Use kubectl patch command to update API objects in place. This subcommand supports JSON patch, JSON merge patch to remove existing env variables.

kubectl patch deployments DEPLOYMENT_NAME --type=json -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/0"}]

To confirm one of the options above are working you may run the “kubectl describe deployment deployment_name” and you’ll see that the environment are being updated/removed but not in the yaml.

When removing existing env variables from deployment configuration in environment variables under .template.spec.containers[].env[] of Deployment's Pod template from which the actual state of pods changes to a new set of pods with the desired Environment variables at the controlled rate. Therefore, you may use the status of the Deployment as an indicator for any stuck updates of your env variables, consider to rollback a Deployment that is not stable, revisions are saved if and only if the Deployment's Pod template is changed, for example if you update the labels or container images of the template.

